# Inserting county names on a map

Tags: graphics, geography, geographics

I'm attempting to insert the county names on a map of Florida:

```
 counties = 
  Join @@ EntityValue[{Entity[
      "AdministrativeDivision", {"Florida", "UnitedStates"}]}, 
    EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Subdivisions"]];

 countynames = EntityValue[counties, "CanonicalName"];

countyshortnames = Table[StringDrop[StringDrop[ToString[countynames[[i]]],-30], 1], {i, 1, Length[counties]}];

loc = EntityValue[counties, "Position"];

GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], GeoStyling["OutlineMap"],Polygon /@ counties, Table[GeoMarker[loc[[j]],Style[countyshortnames[[j]], TextAlignment -> Center, Black, FontSize -> 10, Bold]], {j, 1,Length@countyshortnames}]},GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that the labels turn out very unruly and I would appreciate if anyone can give me some other approach to do this task.  Thank you!

Comment: By the way you can just write `countyshortnames=StringDrop[#, -6] & /@ countynames[[All, 1]]`

Answer (score 11):

**Update:**

The use of `Geomarker` to insert (text) labels is probably not correct as the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoMarker.html) indicates that the marker type should be a `Graphics` or `Image`.

According to [@C.E. comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146921/create-geolabels-with-date-objects#comment394857_146921) in a related post, instead of using `Geomarker` to insert labels, it is possible to use directly the `Text`primitive. In your case :

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick,Black}],GeoStyling["OutlineMap"],Polygon/@counties,
Table[Text[Style[countyshortnames[[j]],TextAlignment->Center,Black,FontSize->10,Bold],loc[[j]]],
{j,1,Length@countyshortnames}]},GeoBackground->None,ImageSize->1200]
```

[image]

**Previous:**

The problem seems to be the default `"Scale"` of the [`GeoMarker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoMarker.html) primitive. Setting for example the option `"Scale"->1` for all your geomarkers seems to work. That means :

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], GeoStyling["OutlineMap"],Polygon /@ counties, 
Table[GeoMarker[loc[[j]],Style[countyshortnames[[j]], TextAlignment -> Center, Black, FontSize -> 10, Bold], 
"Scale"->1], {j, 1,Length@countyshortnames}]},GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Have a great Memorial Day weekend!

Comment: If I wanted to do this for North Carolina, how to get MMA to drop the word "County"?

Comment: @gotwals Just replace `countyshortnames[[j]]` with `StringDrop[countyshortnames, -6][[j]]`