# create geolabels with date-objects

Tags: plotting, geography, geographics

I want to create a `GeoGraphics` with customised labels. The example dataset is:

```
LLdata = {{GeoPosition[{41.126257`, 22.517745`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{41.126273`, 22.517745`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{41.126286`, 22.517742`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{41.126289`, 22.517737`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{41.12629`, 22.517746`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{41.126303`, 22.517746`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{41.126305`, 22.517747`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{48.345056`, 12.117888`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.204353`, 4.444874`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.789611`, 4.655464`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.789614`, 4.655437`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.789619`, 4.65544`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.789619`, 4.655441`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.789621`, 4.655445`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.78963`, 4.655437`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
    2.`]}, {GeoPosition[{51.226705`, 4.425997`}], 
   DateObject[{2016, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.`]}}
```

To create a `GeoGraphics` graphic I wrote this code:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoPath[LLdata[[All, 1]]], 
  Polygon[EntityClass["Country", 
    "Europe"]], {Red, Opacity[.9], AbsolutePointSize[10], 
     Point[#]} & /@ LLdata[[All, 1]]}, GeoScaleBar -> "Metric", 
 ImageSize -> Large, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["CountryBorders"], 
 GeoRange -> {{40, 60}, {0, 40}}, GeoRangePadding -> Full]
```

[image]

Who has a suggestion for how to plot the red datapoints in combination with the date objects in this `GeoGraphics`?

Comment: What is a "geographic card"? Would it be sufficient to have the points on your map be labeled with the corresponding dates?

Comment: "geographic card" is the card created by GeoGraphics. Indeed, it's sufficient to labeled the points with the corresponding dates. But how?

Comment: I reformulated the question to avoid "card" since it was causing confusion.

Comment: What about using `Text`? `LLdata /. {pos_GeoPosition, date_} :> Text[DateString[date], pos]` seems to work.

Comment: @C.E. Your solution is actually what should be applied to this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146899/19960) also !