# Add Text to GeoMarker

Tags: geographics

I have been going through the documentation of [`GeoMarker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoMarker.html).

But I do not see any way to add text to these `GeoMarker`s. I would like to number them, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can use `Text` with a `GeoPosition`, which could be the position of the marker with a small offset. Please see my comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146921/731) or the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146908/731).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a custom value to your GeoMarker you can do as follows:

```
cities = {Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Padova", "Veneto", "Italy"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Palermo", "Sicily", "Italy"}]};  

 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], 
 MapThread[{GeoMarker[#1], White, 
 Text[Style[#2, Bold], #1, {0, -2.5}]} &, {cities, {"10", "45", 
 "120"}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) and its third argument to place the label in the correct position.

```
cities = {Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Padova", "Veneto", "Italy"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Palermo", "Sicily", "Italy"}]};

GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], 
  Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], 
  MapIndexed[{GeoMarker[#1], White, Text[Style[First[#2], Bold], #1, {0, -2.5}]} &, cities]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]